# VS2010 support in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, visual-studio-2010, windows-8-upgrade

I've bought Windows 8 and I am ready to make the move. I currently have Windows 7 Professional x64 and I don't think I'll have any problems during the update.

Except for one single program so far: Visual Studio 2010.

I do usually work with VS2012 (so for those who will suggest the upgrade, I agree), but I still need to support old projects built into VS2010. Migrating them to a newer version is not an option.

I've investigated a little bit and heard of a couple of patches that would provide the compatibility. I have installed those and they haven't helped yet. I am verifying the compatibility with Microsoft's Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant.

When my search started taking me into advice of poor credibility, I gave up on my search and decided to ask here.

So, how can i run VS2010 in Win 8?

Comment: I've built some projects from the command line on Windows Server 2012, and had no issues.

Comment: VS 2010 runs just fine on Windows 8. Are you running into a specific problem? Maybe Try Windows 8 in a VM first and install VS 2010 there and check it out against your projects. I'm typing this on Windows 8 Pro and have VS 2010 (and VS 2012, to be fair) both installed. If there's something specific you want me to try on it I can...

Comment: It works just fine, just make sure you put SP1 on top of your RTM install and away you go. And for what it's worth, it probably works without SP1. Anecdote: I have Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012 on my Windows 8 box and they all work.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was guiding myself with the upgrade assistant, which claimed it to be incompatible. I'll try the update soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ignore the warning. I've upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and VS2010 (with installed Sp1) still worked fine.

Comment: Thank you! I though I could trust that assistant. Just upgraded and everything seems to work ok.

Comment: Anecdote: I run VS2008, 2010 and 2012 on Windows 8.